# Issue with jwt-bearer authorization grant in Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory

There are two ASP.NET Core Web APIs that use bearer token authentication. The services also serve static files which are used to consent the APIs into the directory of a consuming application. So both APIs have implicit flow enabled in Azure AD.

API2 is calling into API1 from the Web API controller using the jwt-bearer grant. API2 has permission to access API1.

A user from a third directory navigates to the SPA served by API2. The user is redirected to Azure AD, signs in and consents the API. The user is redirected back to the SPA application and an AJAX call is made to the API2 web API. From that controller, another call is made to API1. This call is authenticated using the jwt-bearer grant (`urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer`).

When the AcquireToken call is made with client credentials for API2 and the JWT token used to call into API2, Azure AD responds with an error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: 
AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid.
Trace ID: 4031717e-aa0c-4432-bbd1-b97a738d3e6f
Correlation ID: 61ae6cd6-6df6-49ee-9145-c16570c28f7b
Timestamp: 2017-02-13 22:44:01Z ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest). ---> System.Exception: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid.\r\nTrace ID: 4031717e-aa0c-4432-bbd1-b97a738d3e6f\r\nCorrelation ID: 61ae6cd6-6df6-49ee-9145-c16570c28f7b\r\nTimestamp: 2017-02-13 22:44:01Z","error_codes":[50027,50027],"timestamp":"2017-02-13 22:44:01Z","trace_id":"4031717e-aa0c-4432-bbd1-b97a738d3e6f","correlation_id":"61ae6cd6-6df6-49ee-9145-c16570c28f7b"}
```

Can anyone tell me what this error means? The JWT token itself is correct, it must be one of the claims inside that Azure AD dislikes.

I have the sample apps and repro steps in [this github repo](https://github.com/marcelvandendungen/jwt-bearer-grant).

**EDIT**
A diagram may clarify what I'm trying to do. It's the interaction #3 that is giving me the error. It uses a ClientCredential with ClientId of API2 and a ClientSecret (or key) and the orange JWT token issued by directory3 with an audience of API2. 
[image]

The orange JWT token looks like:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Il9VZ3FYR190TUxkdVNKMVQ4Y2FIeFU3Y090YyIsImtpZCI6Il9VZ3FYR190TUxkdVNKMVQ4Y2FIeFU3Y090YyJ9.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.lhwEL3x3Cu66l-Dt-hWmH2DrmCCX2YORGhl4x4_13_lZuUVhMr1OFLUdJ4MZRWG5DJMc8F_SyC4XdDiStwFDaLSI_4L6noXNau3KF6Su3PnqD-FoXoQPtmPPmFrDRZ7nPEtSazEcd9HeSwgVvRZywJRBKQqQQtBGBpS7-Y9kxrO-moUhnBdJJ-gwhu_wxwdEZaOuLs68sZuFaONAunElMKO1iYlC9VHP5xrVzh3ErnRSIp3xmgJNmlbf-9AFUSrjN5UaFjfpGGGJIvoaKbL6rq-J1XNpvKZDFYvoC7RMkqS1KM-lu-EI7-QCksb3NKhTg6J_bz5uxmjYltjKanWbUg

Comment: Would you be able to share your access token with personal information scrubbed out? Also in your message you say "When the AcquireToken call is made with client credentials for API2 and the JWT token used to call into API2". Is this a typo? You mean "call into API1"?

Comment: Have you checked this official example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L137 ?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Thanks for your response. No, it's not a typo. I added a diagram to clarify what I'm trying to do. It's interaction #3 that is causing the error.

Comment: @juunas Yes, that is the example I started off from. I added a diagram to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Okay, I get your scenario. `f92c4b91-9567-4cb8-9280-2bac452bfce1` is API2's client id right? One thing that is curious is that there are no scopes in the token. Have you added a permission requirement to the SPA for API2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to enable the API2 could onbehalfof the user to acquire the token for API1, we need to grant the API1 to API2 when we register the API2 in the Directory2 like below:
[image]

Then since the service principal of API1 is also not created in **Directory3**, we need to sign-in the API1 first to to create the service principal of API1 on **Directory3** tenant.

When the users sign-in the SPA from **Directory3** and send the request to the API2, in the code you were acquire the token from **Directory2**. We should acquire the token from the tenant of users(**Directory3**).

And in the code, you were acquiring the token using the **clientId**, in this secnario, we should use the `ClientCredential` like below:

```
var result = await adal.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred, userAssertion);
```

After changing, the code works well for me. Please let me know whether it helps.

In addition, the scenario you are developing is like below and you can refer the detail from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#related-content).
[image]

Comment: Thanks Fei, excellent answer. I have a few things.
`we need to grant the API1 to API2 when we register the API2 in the Directory2`
I may have changed the app definition after consenting it into directory2 originally.

`we need to sign-in the API1 first to to create the service principal of API1 on Directory3 tenant.`
This is a problem. I thought I could get around this by specifying the 'knownClientApplications' property in the manifest, but that does not work for apps in different tenants. It this a feature that will be released soon? API2 is using API1 and is branded differently.

Comment: `in the code you were acquire the token from Directory2. We should acquire the token from the tenant of users(Directory3).`
Of course, that makes sense.

`you were acquiring the token using the clientId, in this secnario, we should use the ClientCredential`
Ah, this was a bug. Picked the wrong overload.

Comment: @MvdD Based on my understanding, that feature maybe not release. Because since the app are in different tenant, normally the organization of app1 have no access to update the `knownClientApplications` of app2. Of course if you have any ideas and feedback about Azure AD, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: What did you mean the bug?  As far as I know when we acquire the token using the **Delegated User Identity with OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of**,  the second tier web application require the first tire web API provider both the users' credential and the first-tier web application's credential so that, the second tier web API could provide the result based on there information. More detail you can refer [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686673/how-to-access-graph-api-from-a-web-api-with-adal-js-issued-implicit-grant-token).

Comment: Directory1 is owned by my company, directory2 is owned by an ISV. They need to register their app with us anyway, so at that point we could update the `knownClientApplications` with their app id.

Comment: I meant that I was already creating the ClientCredential, but picked the wrong `AcquireTokenAsync` overload, passing in only the clientId.

Comment: I filed a feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18274459-make-knownclientapplications-manifest-property-wor